# Adding custom page tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm struggling to work out how to actually add/show the tab on my page. I'm following the instructions here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

but I can't see how to access the app's profile page.

The only options I have under Related links are:

Use Debug Tool
Use Graph API Explorer
See App Timeline View
Promote with an Advert
Translate your App
Delete app

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Comment: I think the only way to add the app to your page would be the `add to page dialog` mentioned by @rennacs. Creating a profile for the app will not give you the option `add to my page` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are a little late on those docs. An app no longer gets a profile page.  Check out [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/) for more information

Comment: Half true, they don't get it automatically. You can still create a Facebook Page for your App by hand in the Developer App ;-)

Comment: Sorry just to clarify all I'm trying to do is add a custom tab to my page. What am I missing?!

Comment: The new dialog linked here is the new way for app developers to install their app onto pages, but there's also a direct API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy utility for adding Tabs to Pages:
https://static.nodesc.com/api/